# Call external function with parameter in onswipe jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe

I have a function that already defined. I need to to call the function with parameters when the jQuery `swipe` event occurs.

Here is the code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#next").on("swiperight",myFunction('right')); 
  $("#next").on("swipeleft",myFunction('left')); 

  function myFunction(direction) {
    var dir = direction;
    console.log(dir);
  }
});
```

But id doesn't works onswipe. Instead it works twice on page load and prints `right` and `left` in console.

It works when the function is called without arguments like,

```
$("#next").on("swipeleft",myFunction);
```

What is the problem here ? Appreciate for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Callback functions have no name. Wrap your named functions inside it:

```
  $("#next").on("swiperight",function(){myFunction('right')}); 
  $("#next").on("swipeleft",function(){myFunction('left')});
```